# React-Redux unique key warning on store change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm working on a todo app and everything works fine when it first loads in. However, when I add a new todo and the store updates, I get the unique key warning, when the key is defined in the array components:

```
render() {
    const todoList = this.props.todos.map(todo => {
        return <Todo todo={todo} key={todo._id}/>
    })
    return (
        <div className={styles.todoContainer}>
            {todoList}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Todo Component:

```
return (
    <div className={styles.todo}>
        <h2 className={styles.todoText}>{props.todo.name}</h2>
    </div>
);
```

Adding todo:

```
//actions.js
export function addTodo(todo){
    let config = {
        headers: { 
            token: localStorage.getItem('token')
        }
    };
    return function(dispatch){
        return axios.post('http://localhost:8082/api/todos/create', todo, config)
            .then(msg => {
                dispatch({type: ADD_TODO, payload: todo})
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
}

//reducer.js
case ADD_TODO:
    const data = [...state.data];
    data.push(action.payload);
    return {
        ...state,
        data: data
    };
```

Is this a problem I should worry about fixing, or is it a bug? Thanks!

Comment: When adding a new todo to the list, are you generating a unique `_id` for it ?

Comment: Yes, the `_id` comes from a mongoDB database. Also console logged it and every key was unique.

Comment: could you please share the code that's responsible for adding a new todo ?

Comment: Added more information above

Comment: You are adding a todo from the frontend to the list, propably it doesn't have the `_id` attribute, tbh I wanted to see the code that you construct the todo parameter you are passing to the action as payload.

Comment: Thanks, I realized I wasn't doing anything with the todo I got from the axios call.